# Como cambiar el contenido de un div desde un menú? React

Tags: reactjs

tengo un componente, que tiene dos div un panel y un contenido y querio cambiar el contenido de acuerdo al panel [image: Imagen actual del menu]

Cada boton es un componente y cada casa es otro

```js
function Panel() {
    const changemenu = () =>{

    }
    return (
        <div className="panel">
            <div className="control">
                <Button>Step 1</Button>
                <Button>Step 2</Button>
                <Button>Step 3</Button>
            </div>
            <div className="content">
                <House name='House 1' img='1'/>
                <House name='House 2' img='1'/>
                <House name='House 3' img='1'/>
                <House name='House 4' img='1'/>
                <House name='House 5' img='1'/>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Quisiera poder mostrar solo la info correspondiente a ese menú

Sabrá alguien si se pude hacer con css o  donde puedo encontrar la información para usar una función de js en el componente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo te recomendaría que usaras alguna librería que ya tiene eso implementado como material ui el componente tabs.

De todas maneras, si lo quieres hacer a tu manera, lo haría así:

```
const houses = [{name: "House1", step: 1, img: "1"},{name: "House2", step: 1, img: "1"},{name: "House3", step: 2, img: "1"},{name: "House4", step: 3, img: "1"}];

function Panel() {
    const [filteredHouses, setFilteredHouses] = useState([]);
    const [step, setStep] = useState(1);

    useEffect(()=>{
        setFilteredHouses(houses.filter(x => x.step === step))
    },[step])

    const changemenu = (step) =>{
        setStep(step);
    }
    return (
        <div className="panel">
            <div className="control">
                <Button onClick={()=> changemenu(1)}>Step 1</Button>
                <Button onClick={()=> changemenu(2)}>Step 2</Button>
                <Button onClick={()=> changemenu(3)}>Step 3</Button>
            </div>
            <div className="content">
                {filteredHouses.map((x,index)=>{
                     return <House key={index} name={x.name} img={x.img} />
                })}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

También debes de Agregar la función Onclick en el componente Button para llamar al evento

```
function Button(props){
return(
    <button
    className="button" onClick={props.onClick} >
        {props.children}
    </button>
);
}
```

Comment: Que librearía recomendarías? Soy nuevo en React js

Comment: Como te dije antes, Material UI https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/installation

Comment: @MoisesHernandez debe ser el autor de la respuesta quien agregue el código adicional que proporcionaste. Podrías, por ejemplo, sugerirlo como comentario para que luego edite su respuesta, o crear una respuesta adicional explicando el funcionamiento del código.